# The Qt program runs but the popup window doesn't display anything

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have been trying to run the code. It runs successfully but and I can see the popup window but it doesn't show anything. You can see the popup image below.

**This is what pops up**
[image]

And you can see my code below:

***This is the Header file***

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QSpinBox>
#include <QSlider>
#include <QDial>
#include <QProgressBar>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QSpinBox *spinbox;
    QSlider *slider1;
    QDial *dial;
    QProgressBar *progressbar;

public:
    MainWindow();
    //~MainWindow();
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

***This is the MainWindow file***

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QGridLayout>

MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
    spinbox = new QSpinBox;
    slider1 = new QSlider(Qt::Horizontal);
    dial = new QDial;
    progressbar = new QProgressBar;

    QVBoxLayout *lay1 = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    //QGridLayout *lay1 = new QGridLayout(this);

    lay1 -> addWidget(spinbox);
    lay1 -> addWidget(slider1);
    lay1 -> addWidget(dial);
    lay1 -> addWidget(progressbar);

    setLayout(lay1);
}
```

***This is the Main file***

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Please don't post your images as links -- you can insert pics right into your question when you create it.

Comment: As for why your window is blank -- don't you need to do it like `foo = new Foo(this)` so your objects have a parent?

Comment: Fixed it, still doesn't work

Comment: Reading https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#details It's look like your MainWindow miss a central widget

Comment: Do you not see any warnings at the console?  You shouldn't call `setLayout` in a `QMainWindow` -- it already has its own layout manager to handle toolbars, dock widgets etc.  Use [`QMainWindow::setCentralWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#setCentralWidget) instead.

Comment: @G.M. I have actually ran this code in another computer and it worked. I don't know why it doesn't work in my computer